# How to have the max value selected inside a select

Tags: php, html

I have the following:

**PHP CODE**:

```
<select name="valoracion<?php echo $i; ?>" id="valoracion<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <?php
    for($h=1; $h<6; $h++){
        echo '<option value="'.$h.'">'.$h.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

**This prints**:

```
<select name="valoracion0" id="valoracion0">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

When this `<select>` appears I want by default for the selected value to be the max number. How can I do this?

Comment: `if h==5 echo selected` (pseudocode)

Comment: Since the max number is always the last number in your case, simply check whether or not you have reached it within your loop, and if so output the `checked` attribute on the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
<select name="valoracion<?php echo $i; ?>" id="valoracion<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <?php
    for($h=1; $h<6; $h++){
       if($h == 5){
         echo '<option value="'.$h.'" selected >'.$h.'</option>'; 
       }else{
        echo '<option value="'.$h.'">'.$h.'</option>';
       }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this..

```
<select name="valoracion<?php echo $i; ?>" id="valoracion<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <?php
    $cnt=6;$sel=""; // <--- Add a variable $sel with nothing assigned
    for($h=1; $h<$cnt; $h++){
        if($h==($cnt-1)) //<-- Here goes the check
        {
            $sel="Selected";
        }
        echo '<option '.$sel.' value="'.$h.'">'.$h.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Even though you are correct I believe you complicated it too much imo

Comment: It's not complicated , but it is _generalized_. Say if you want to change `$h<9` , then you need to change on your `if` too. I know you won't understand what I am saying ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<select name="valoracion<?php echo $i; ?>" id="valoracion<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <?php
    for($h=1; $h<6; $h++){
        if($h == 5){ $selected = " selected=\"selected\""; }else{ $selected = NULL; }
        echo '<option value="'.$h.'"'.$selected.'>'.$h.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```